# Is REST or SOAP better for spatial data analysis

Tags: qgis, rest, soap

I am working on agriculture forecasting project. It is the integration of SOA, web services, ontologies etc.

What is better for spatial data analysis, REST or SOAP?

WMS, WFS are used but either use REST or SOAP?

I am going to use QGIS.

Comment: It heavily depends on your architecture and business logic. If you are unsure I would recommend REST because it is more popular and it is more flexible. But again it is not really grateful to give recommendation without more context.

Answer (score 2):

REST & SOAP are request/response theories and orthogonal concerns to spatial data analysis. REST is more popular in open-source code, so if you're *designing* an application, look to it first, but as far as using existing code, this shouldn't be a major decision.

Answer (score 0):

I think this presentation might be helpful to your question: http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit09/papers/keynote_chappell.pdf

REST is lighter, better for web applications. ESRI has been transitioning from SOAP to REST recently.